# Shortcode in wordpress post is not showing in proper place

Tags: wordpress

I have generated these shortcodes.Whenever I am using these short codes in some particular place posts and pages are not showing in the right place.It comes at the beginning of the content.
Can anyone help me out here?

```
function __construct()
{
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($this,'my_auction_creator_activation' ));
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this,'my_auction_creator_custom_field' ));
    add_action( 'save_post', array($this,'my_auction_creator_form_save' ));
    add_shortcode('myauctioncreator_listing' , array($this,'ebay_listing' )); 
    add_shortcode('myauctioncreator_ads' , array($this,'ebay_ads' )); 
    add_shortcode('myauctioncreator_profile' , array($this,'ebay_profile' )); 
    add_shortcode('myauctioncreator_feedback' , array($this,'ebay_feedback' )); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the output of the shortcode, are you using print or echo?

If you are, you should be returning the content instead. Using print or echo will cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting exactly same issue as i was echo the contents

use like this

```
  function shortcode_function()
  {
    ob_start();
    //some echo or html code goes here
    echo "<p>this is paragraph</p>";
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
```

Comment: pl. do upvote or accept the answer. i am learning wordpress too so if any need contact me